# azure application gateway 502 errors with service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-gateway

I have a service fabric with multiple web apps / APIs running on multiple ports. For example:

```
http://cluster.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:9012/app1

http://cluster.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:9013/app2
```

and so on.

I am trying to configure application gateway to with a custom domain and SSL offload, but i am getting 502 error. This is what i configured:

- Back end pool - added both the VM scaleset public IP and load SF load balancer FQDN (cluster.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com)
- HTTP settings - added HTTP on port 9012 (http://cluster.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:9012/app1)
- Listener - added HTTPS listener on port 443 with SSL certificate
- Rules - basic rule to combine all above

I can access the web apps/services via public IP and SF load balance (http://cluster.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:9012/app1), but when i try the gateway, i am getting 502 error. The MSDN documentation doesn't seem to help much. My question would be, what do i need to configure to support SF apps on a custom port (9012,9013, etc in my case) to work with 443 port in gateway and custom domain/SSL

Comment: HI,@Alex ,Did you refer this offcial document to troubleshoot your issue?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502

Comment: Hi @alex  Could you please post here how you solved this 502 error.  Our production release is getting delayed due to this .We are getting this 502 error intermittently  at least once or two times in a week.